# Match strings with key dataframe and assign a value

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I am working with some text in `R` and I would like to complete a task related to compare the strings from one dataframe against the strings saved in other dataframe and when there is coincidence assign a value in the first dataframe. My initial dataframe is `DF1`:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(v1=c("A cat in sun", "A silver arrow", "A deep sun"), v2=c(1,2,3),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Where `v1` is the variable of text to make a contrast. `DF2` is the dataframe where the chains of text are saved to make the comparison:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(key = c("arrow|spyder|car", "cat|met|shoe", "sun|moon|earth"), value = c("D","M", "A"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then, the comparison must be done for each row in `DF1` using `v1` and `key` from `DF2` to assign `value`. I have tested with `grepl` using only values like:

```
grepl("cat|met|shoe", "A cat in sun")
```

And this works, but the issue is when I try to use the same logic inside `DF1` with a structure like this:

```
DF1$Var <- DF2[grepl(DF2$key, DF1$v1), "value"]
```

I can't get the expected result:

```
DF3 <- data.frame(v1=c("A cat in sun", "A silver arrow", "A deep sun"), v2=c(1,2,3), Var = c("M", "D", "A"),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df1$Var <- lapply(df1$v1, function(x) 
  df2[min(which(lapply(df2$key, function(y) grepl(y,x))==T)),"value"])
df1
```

**Output is:**

```
              v1 v2 Var
1   A cat in sun  1   M
2 A silver arrow  2   D
3     A deep sun  3   A
```

**Sample data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("A cat in sun", "A silver arrow", "A deep sun"
), v2 = c(1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(key = c("arrow|spyder|car", "cat|met|shoe", "sun|moon|earth"
), value = c("D", "M", "A")), .Names = c("key", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to assign the first possible `value` (e.g., `M` to the first row due to "cat" but not `A` due to "sun"), then we may also write simply

```
for(i in nrow(DF2):1)
  DF1$value[grep(DF2$key[i], DF1$v1)] <- DF2$value[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

My one liner solution.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

DF1 %>% regex_inner_join(DF2, by = c(v1 = "key"))  %>% select(v1,v2,value)  %>% filter (! duplicated(v1))  %>% dplyr::rename(Var = value)
```

**Result**

```
         v1       v2    Var
   A cat in sun   1      M
 A silver arrow   2      D
     A deep sun   3      A
```